# Why are bright textures showing up in shadows on EEVEE?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I made a procedural material for a moon and in the shadows you can see bright parts of the moon, it should be all shadow. I'm only using 1 directional light but I think the problem lies with my procedural background world material. So I guess the question is, how do I get the world material to not affect my objects textures/lighting?

I have included the moon and the material of that moon screenshots plus a link to the world material tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvkW7PDni40

[image: moon] [image: material shot1]

[image: material shot2]

Comment: From first look I'd say, the craters have very bright edges. On the light side you don't see it that much because all the material is lit up very bright. In the terminator it starts to show, the craters have bright rings around them. And the shadow side is not all black but has a faint light on it, so the bright areas appear bright in shadows as well. I guess you should decrease the white values... Looking at the nodes where you are adding and dividing and all without clamping, I could imagine the white values are even way beyond 1, what makes them not only bright but super bright.

Comment: I don't see a file, but DFR seems to have one-- what am I missing?  I'd say, it's probably specular lighting in combination with an over-powerful bump (when the moon should have pretty close to zilch specular), but the other half of the equation are the lights.  In this case, you should be looking at one or two sun lamps (earth and sun), and a flat world.  Your world (ambient lighting, background lighting) looks way too bright, and probably too variable.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a color ramp between the base color and the divide i was able to fix it[image]